# preserve inline variable with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, sudo

Hi i'm trying to make something like this to work in bash

```
$ http=xx sudo echo $http
xx
```

but i keep getting an empty line, the only thing that works so far is:

```
$ export http=xx
$ sudo -E echo $http
xx
```

what i would like to achieve is the ability to inline a variable for the sudo command

i also tried this as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202384/140910)

```
$ sudo http=xx echo $http
```

but with no luck, am i missing something?

Comment: How about `export http=xx; sudo -E echo $http`? It works, but can you use it like that with a semicolon?

Comment: You probably don't need to do this. Your example is too simple, and could simply be replaced by `sudo echo xx` with no variable involved. If this isn't acceptable for some reason, please show something closer to your actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the first command is that `http` variable expansion happens before it is set.

```
$ http=xx sudo echo $http
```

Try instead

```
$ http=xx sudo -E bash -c 'echo $http'
```

The syntax is described in `man env`

```
   Some have suggested that env is redundant since the same effect is achieved by:

          name=value ... utility [ argument ... ]
```

Otherwise if the goal is not to affect current shell environment the export and sudo command can be done in a subshell:

```
$ ( export http=xx ; sudo -E 'echo $http' )
```

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul There will just be no output, you are setting the env for `sudo` not `bash -c`. You can set vars inside sudo anyway though so you can do `sudo http=xx bash -c 'echo $http'`

Comment: `env` isn't redundant; it allows adding names to the environment that aren't valid shell identifiers. `env "foo:bar=3" someCommand`.

Comment: Thanks that works, i ended up using this syntax that i like more: 
    sudo http=xx bash -c 'echo $http'

Comment: `sudo -E` leads to all of the user's environment variables being brought in, which may have unintended consequences.  However, setting the intended variable just _after_ sudo works perfectly well: `sudo http=xx bash -c 'echo $http'`

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me very similar to an already discussed case:

what if you do:

```
sudo http=xx su root -c 'echo "$http"'
```

Try to have a look here 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202383/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-sudo-su